# How to get the 3D coordinates if the coordinates on the ground would be known?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am doing a project related with image processing and computer vision on the game FIFA 21. Through line detection i've found the corner points of the penalty area and the goalkeeper area. With making a coordinate system i've been able to transform the play into a bird's eye view (see image on the left) with the following lines:

```
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pt1, pt2)
new_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (cols, rows))
```

Here pt1 are the points of where I want the coordinates to be in the bird's eye view and pt2 are the points gathered from the normal playing field. With the coordinates of the ball in the minimap in the bottom of the screen, i was able to find where the ball should be if it was going on the ground as opposed to through the air as what is happening in the image. On the following image on the left you can see how the ball that was in the air is projected on the bird's eye view, and where the ball would be if it was on the ground.

[Ball in FIFA projected on bird's eye view and compared with ball on the ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDowr.jpg)

What i want to achieve is knowing what the height of the ball is at this point as shown in the image. It is also possible to project where the ball would be on the full field if it was low to compare it with the ball through the air (as shown in balck on the right in the image). My question thus is how can i get the height (z-coordinate) of the ball within this frame knowing the matrix from the transform etc?

Comment: From a single image, you can't tell the height. By what magic do you have the ball on the ground ?